# Spring Boot Memory Calculator does not use container memory limits

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am running a container on kubernetes that I build using `spring-boot-maven-plugin 2.5.0`.
I have tried to use `paketobuildpacks/builder 0.1.127-base` and `0.1.115-base`.

When I start my pod it shows the following:

```
Calculating JVM memory based on 3353816K available memory
```

However these are the requests/limits that is returned by `kubectl describe pod`:

```
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   1Gi
```

I read that the memory calculator should base it on these memory limits.
What can I do so the memory calculator does it calculation based on the container memory?
I hope someone can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the memory calculator does not work with cgroups v2.
My colleague has created a pull request for the buildpack at https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/libjvm/pull/82

For now we change some kernel parameters so the old naming convention is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will consist of three parts.

### Kubernetes

As you correctly pointed out containers can detect all node's memory where pod is scheduled.

```
$ free -h # run in host OS
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        949M        1.3G        2.0M        1.6G        2.7G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu2 -- free -h # run in a pod's container
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       961Mi       1.3Gi       2.0Mi       1.6Gi       2.7Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

If `requests` and `limits` and not specified, containers can consume all node's memory (and cpu as well). What is responsible for what:

- `requests` - minimum amount of memory which is required to schedule the pod with container on the worker-node. This should be reasonable figure because if it's too big, it will be difficult to scheduler to find a node where it can start this pod. It's possible and allowed for a container to consume more memory than requested.
- `limits` - limits maximum amount of memory to be allocated to the containers. Once container exceeds the limit, it will be evicted and re-created.

[Motivation for memory requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#motivation-for-memory-requests-and-limits)

### JVM apps in Kubernetes

In the past when java applications were hosted on on-premise instances, it was well-known how much memory is available and how much memory application is allowed to consume.

Since all clusters are different and containers can see the whole amount of memory on the worker nodes, `JVM` memory options should be defined. In kubernetes with usage of `requests` and `limits` it's possible to provide exactly required amount of memory for the container with the application and match it with allocated `JVM heap memory`.

There are different options available for setting up `JVM` options. Most common related to heap memory are:

[Explicit Heap Memory – Xms and Xmx Options](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-parameters#explicit-heap-memory---xms-and-xmx-options)

### How to pass it to containers in kubernetes

There are already two good answers on StackOverflow which solves similar question.

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62335341/15537201) and
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68040788/15537201)

In short words they cover how to pass options to `JVM` using [kubernetes environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) e.g. `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.

### Useful links:

(please get familiar with it):

- [Heap size, memory usage and resource limits in k8s for JVM applications](https://akobor.me/posts/heap-size-and-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-for-jvm-applications)
- [Sizing Kubernetes pods for JVM apps without fearing the OOM Killer](https://srvaroa.github.io/jvm/kubernetes/memory/docker/oomkiller/2019/05/29/k8s-and-java.html)